# How to populate json data in drop down using angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, json

My html code is

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="person in persons">{{ person.data }}</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
```

My js code is

```
var app=angular.module("mainApp",[]); 
  app.controller("myController",function ($scope,$http){
     $http.get("my url")
     .success(function(response){
        $scope.persons=response;
   });
});
```

My json code is:

```
data:["bank1","bank2",bank3"]
```

It is fetching all the data in one single line.. How to get it in drop down box?? I want the data to drop down as list.

Anyone help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: data of a particular person in drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select ng-model="SelectedPerson" ng-options="person for person in persons.data"></select>
```

Update :

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29507/) :

Comment: @shilpa I have added working demo. kindly checkout it

Comment: If you pass correct array object then it's working well.

Comment: i need to fetch the json data through an api using http request, not manually, My json is in this format  [{"status": "success", "data": ["bank1","bank2","bank3",bank4"]} i need to get "data" in drop down list @Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: No prob. it will be work. that's why I have mentioned `persons.data` in `ng-options`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <select>
        <option ng-repeat="person in persons.data">{{person}}</option>
      </select>
     </div>
</body>
```